# Package not importing in Colab after updating Python version

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working in **Colab** and trying to use a package that **requires Python 3.9**, but Colab runs natively on **Python 3.7**. I updated the Python version in Colab and installed the package as such:

```bash
#install python 3.9
!sudo apt-get update -y &> /dev/null
!sudo apt-get install python3.9 &> /dev/null

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1 &> /dev/null
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2 &> /dev/null

!sudo apt-get install python3-pip &> /dev/null
!sudo apt install python3.9-distutils &> /dev/null
!python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip &> /dev/null

# Install package
!python3.9 -m pip install mypackage
```

The only problem is that when I try

```py
import mypackage
```

I get an `ModuleNotFoundError` saying that the module was not installed. I assume this is because Colab is looking in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/`, rather than the corresponding path for `python3.9`.

Has anyone run into this issue / know what to do here? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. I switched to Python 3.8, and when I got the python version in the environment, it seemed to be working as expected. But when it comes to package importing, it imports it from Python 3.7 folder! So confusing... Any solution?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after spending a little time on this problem, I finally found a workaround that might help you get over this problem. It might not be the best way to deal with the problem, but at least worked for me.

```py
import sys

# Add the dist-package directory of Python3.8 to the path

sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/')
```

Comment: You should add this code snippet before importing the line that you try to import the 
 from Python3.8 dist-packages.